# What app has the most comprehensive selection of English-translated digital manga?

Tags: resources

I've been wanting to start reading more English-translated digital manga on my Kindle Fire HD, but I like books published by many different companies, and I'd like to keep any potential digital manga collection I create tied to as few different app sources as I can.

My questions is: is there any digital manga app that currently collects all digitally-published manga? If not, what are some apps that, while not having all series, do offer titles from different publishers, and how extensive is their selection?

As per [Hakase's comment](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/38754/what-app-has-the-most-comprehensive-selection-of-digital-manga#comment52655_38754), info on sources for legal DRM-free English manga would also be appreciated. Ignore if this makes the question too broad.

Comment: Something tells me it's a useless endeavor to try and find one app to rule them all. Consider instead collecting all the mangas you're interested in in downloadable form (not tied to DRM or a specific app) and just building your own personal library, from many different sources. But first you'll have to find which ones you'll want to have.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty much already resigned to no easy solution, but figured I'd ask anyway, on the off chance there's something I haven't heard about. DRM-free would be the ultimate solution, actually, but I don't know of any ways to get those legally. Otherwise I'd jump on it in a heartbeat.

Comment: This question is pointless. As readers/apps add (very often) and remove (sometimes from a region due to licencing) titles, the lists change too much. Today's underdog can seal a deal with Kodansha tomorrow, and rise to top. Stackexchange prefers a timeless or time-independent Q&A, therefore this question should be closed. I also second what @Hakase said

Comment: @Mindwin, many questions in stackoverflow are time dependant. A solution that is working now can be useless in the future as they have demonstrated. I disagree that this should be closed for that reason.

Comment: I don't really think something big like apps signing deals with manga publishers or ending those deals is gonna happen too quickly for the users to be able to maintain the answers to this question, so for that reason I would not close the question. I just don't think there will be any actual answers at all. But let's see.

Comment: @AkiTanaka Yes, English specifically. I'll edit the question to be more specific.